# How to create a simple modal / message for successful email dispatch

Tags: javascript, php, html, mail-form

I want to create a simple modal / message for successful email dispatch. I have a contact form with a PHP mailer. There is a PHP redirect and I don't know how to customize it.

I don't want to have a message for unsuccessful case, because there is a validating script. Can you please give me a hint?

This is the redirect code:

```
   <?php

class Redirect{
    public static function to($location = null) {
        if($location) {
            if(is_numeric($location)) {
                switch($location) {
                    case 404:
                        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                        include 'includes/errors/404.php';
                        exit();
                    break;
                }
            }
            header('Location: ' . $location);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Tell us what you have done, write the code, and if you're having problem with it then ask a specific question.

Comment: I've removed the example site, as readers should not need to exit Stack Overflow to see the essence of the problem. Use screenshots or more descriptions, but try to keep it self-contained. Remember that questions are for posterity, not just individual posters, and that example problems on your own site will be fixed eventually, and thus will not be useful examples to future learners.

Comment: I dont asked anybody to write a code for me - just for some hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can create with simple html and css. Please see the below code.[Lightbox/modal in css](http://jsfiddle.net/oliverdoetsch/BSu96/)

Define a content `<div>` and overlay `<div>` and place the first one over the second (See z-index in css). By default, set its `display:none` and upon lightbox trigger, make it visible (`display:block`)